# Split a string and trim a known prefix from each part in a complex JSON structure

Tags: json, split, jq

I'm dealing with a fairly complex JSON-structure in which a single entry needs to be edited in several places. For example:

```
[
    {
        "name": "test 1",
        "stuff": {
            "properties": {
                "id": 0,
                "stuff_list": [
                    {
                        "entryId": 1,
                        "description": "- item 1\n- item 2\n- item 3"
                    },
                    {
                        "entryId": 2,
                        "description": "- item 1\n- item 2\n- item 3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "test 2",
        "stuff": {
            "properties": {
                "id": 1,
                "stuff_list": [
                    {
                        "entryId": 1,
                        "description": null
                    },
                    {
                        "entryId": 2,
                        "description": "- item 1\n- item 2\n- item 3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Here I would like to edit each `"description"`-element: The string needs to be split at each `\n` and the substrings `"^\n?-\s"` of each resulting array element need to be removed. So it should result in:

```
{
    "entryId": 1,
    "description": ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
}
```

My first approach is:

```sh
jq '.[].stuff.properties.stuff_list[].description | split("\n")' the_file.json
```

but that's not working in the first place becaue of the `null` values that can occur at some places. So now I wonder: how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: You want the whole JSON to be returned as the output? or only `entryId` and `description`?

Comment: The whole JSON with modified entries, yes.

Comment: @oguzismail: Please feel free to retain your answer. Your answer was first and always good  to have an alternate approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate version using `split()` on the `\n` and trimming string `-`  on the left, would be to do

```
.[].stuff.properties.stuff_list[].description |= 
  if . != null then 
    split("\n") | map(ltrimstr("- ")) 
  else 
    . 
  end
```

<sup>[jqplay - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DSsu9Q1ASQ)</sup>

Comment: With the slight modification `else [] end` I find this solution to be even more suitable.